# "Another edit awaiting approval" message not visible in review queue

Tags: bug, review-queues, first-post-review

I was reviewing the First Posts queue and I thought to make a minor edit to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47079327). Clicking the *Edit* button while in the review queue did nothing, so eventually I visited the post directly.

There, once I clicked *Edit* the reason why I couldn't edit was clear.

[image]

I believe the error message should pop-up in the review queue as well.